# Any reason to start a JsonPath without the "$" dollar sign?

Tags: java, jsonpath, jayway

In JsonPath, I've seen the "$" sign described as the symbol that "refers to the root object or element".

Example:

```
JsonPath.read(json, "$.store.book[*].author");
```

**Question**: is there any reason not to start the path with "$"?

In Jayway, you can omit the "$." at the start of a path and get the same result.

But, is there any reason to do this?

Comment: Maybe create an issue about it in https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Smartbear.com's JSON documentation they point out:

> The leading $ represents the root object or array and can be omitted.
>   For example, $.foo.bar and foo.bar are the same, and so are
>   $[0].status and [0].status.

The full document can be viewed [here](https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html).

So looks like the $ sign is simply there for style, which leads to the question of why the JSONPath creators implemented it.